# Mongo-express | Patch file found for package mongodb-query-parser

Tags: gitlab-ci, npm-install, mongo-express

I am trying to get rid of the following error message.

```
patch-package 6.2.2
Applying patches...
Error: Patch file found for package mongodb-query-parser which is not present at node_modules/mongodb-query-parser
```

This message appears when I try to install mongo-express. Locally this is no problem, because `npm install` keeps progressing after the error message.

But when I try to run it on gitlab-pipeline it exits the job.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary quick fix is to install mongo-express without the postinstall.

```
npm install mongo-express --ignore-scripts && npm install
```

That way the patch-package isn't called and at least the CI doesn't break. But I'm not sure how unsecure this is...

Hopefully going to be fix soon! I opened [an issue](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/619)
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for answer! I fixed it by myself by going down to v0.53.0. I'll try your solution later.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g mongo-express@1.0.0-alpha.4
```

Install globally and remove mongo-express from package.json.